# Automapper deep mapping

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I am using EFCore 2.2 and automapper 8.0.0. I have table named folders and it has another table named folderReferences and the code for folder table is:

```
public Guid Id { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<FolderReference> Parents { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<FolderReference> Children { get; set; }
```

And for FolderReference:

```
public Guid ParentId { get; set; }

public Guid ChildId { get; set; }

public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

public virtual Folder Parent { get; set; }

public virtual Folder Child { get; set; }
```

And connections on DatabaseContext:

```
builder
  .Entity<FolderReference>()
  .HasOne(a => a.Parent)
  .WithMany(a => a.Children)
  .HasForeignKey(a => a.ParentId)
  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

builder
  .Entity<FolderReference>()
  .HasOne(a => a.Child)
  .WithMany(a => a.Parents)
  .HasForeignKey(a => a.ChildId)
  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

With automapperConfig:

```
CreateMap<Folder, FolderModel>()
            .ForMember(a => a.ChildrenCount, a => a.MapFrom(b => b.Children.Count))
            .ForMember(a => a.ParentsCount, a => a.MapFrom(b => b.Parents.Count))
            .ForMember(a => a.Parents, a => a.MapFrom(b => b.Parents.Select(c => c.Parent)))
            .ForMember(a => a.Children, a => a.MapFrom(b => b.Children.Select(c => c.Child)));
```

And the folder model:

```
public class FolderModel
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<FolderModel> Parents { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<FolderModel> Children { get; set; }

        public int ParentsCount { get; set; }

        public int ChildrenCount { get; set; }
    }
```

And the call:

```
var folder = await _defaultContext.Folders
     .ProjectTo<FolderModel>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
     .FirstAsync(a => a.Id == folderId, _cancellationToken);

return folder;
```

The problem is when I call the Folders from the database using ProjectTo it shows me this:

```
{
  "id": "c6531829-555a-471e-aa86-09f21ceea720",
  "parents": [],
  "children": [
    {
      "id": "767742ca-6fb0-48f6-a377-f25ee9fbeefc",
      "parents": null,
      "children": null,
      "parentsCount": 2,
      "childrenCount": 0
    },
    {
      "id": "de6642a6-3a49-4cc8-a7d2-3afec075a4b2",
      "parents": null,
      "children": null,
      "parentsCount": 1,
      "childrenCount": 1
    }
  ],
  "parentsCount": 0,
  "childrenCount": 2
}
```

The parents and children are null and I don't know how to make automapper work deeper. I use LazyLoading on navigation properties.
So my question is how to make parents and children work deeper using automapper?

Comment: From what I know, unlike EF6, in EF Core you need to Include everything before ProjectTo.

Comment: @Lucian I don't think this is EF6 or EF Core related. I believe recursive queryable projection is not possible in general, isn't it?

Comment: It depends :) In EF6 some cases are indeed impossible as you say. And others need MaxDepth. I don't know about EF Core, but I think they don't have that constraint which leads to the incompatible initializations exception.

Comment: I tried MaxDepth but it's not working with this case.

Comment: ProjectTo is just a select statement. So if you can do it with LINQ, it should work with ProjectTo too. Otherwise not.

Comment: Yes i agree that it is a select statement, but how i can control the deepth of this select? maybe i need to reconfigure my automapper profile?